# Error Starting Spring ContextLoaderListener

Tags: spring, maven

I am developing a simple web application using Spring framework 3.1.3.RELEASE & MAVEN.  My application would not startup unless I take out the listener from web.xml

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Tomcat reports the following error:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive sampleapp.war
11/12/2012 3:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
11/12/2012 3:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/sampleapp] startup failed due to previous errors
```

My WEB.XML looks as follows:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>EMS</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Application Context File is empty at this point:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">





</beans>
```

Below is the JAR files under WEB-INF/lib

```
eclipselink-2.4.0.jar             
javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar       
mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar   
spring-context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
```

Below is the files under WEB-INF

```
application.properties  
spring-context.xml  
web.xml
```

I understand that:

- ContextLoaderListener is available in spring-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
- If the JAR is available in WEB-INF/lib then it should be picked
  by TOMCAT.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your Spring Bean Definition file and your complete stack trace?

Comment: Thanks Mael, I have updated the question to include the application context file.  It is empty as I just want to get the application up and running before i use DI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was missing Spring Dependencies in my POM file.  I initially had the following dependencies in the POM

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I enabled debugging on tomcat **logging.properties** to see that I was getting a **class ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** as I added dependencies (one at a time) the ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError kept changing until all dependencies were satisfied. The ContextLoaderListener started up OK after that.  The dependencies I added are:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- required by Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem: Move the `spring-context.xml` into `WEB-INF/classes` and set the context param as follows:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

WEB-INF is not in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: I am just trying to use Dependency injection at this stage.  As I might end up using a different MVC framework for the application.  Do i still need to use dispatcher servlet if I only want to use Spring for DI?

Comment: No you don't, DispatcherServlet is only for Spring MVC

Comment: You have to tell the context loader listener where to look for XML, regardless of what servlet you're using.  You didn't say "no Spring MVC", so it's a reasonable assumption that you're using it.  You must have at least one servlet.

Comment: I thought the XML location is specified by the <context-param> parameter in the web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I share duffmo's reasoning, just want to point out, that you can leave the application context in the WEB-INF directory, if you update your config to:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This way your global application context resides in the same directory as the dispatcher configurations.

Comment: Thanks Stefan,  I have actually changed the contextConfigLocation.  I have updated the question to reflect that.  But that did not resolve the issue